# Comparing two Lists - looking for faster and more efficient way

Tags: java, performance, list

I am looking for a better way of comparing two "lists". The idea is : I have 2 lists which are composed of Strings. My method returns true if all Strings from both lists matches. I.E

> List(1) = "foo, foo1, foo2, foo3"
>
> List(2) = "foo, foo1, foo2, foo3"

When comparing these two lists if ALL strings match then the method returns true. If any of the elements do not match then returns false.

Code which i have ( and works ) is this: however i was just wondering if any one could think of a better solution to this problem ?

```
private boolean match(Context messageContext, ContextRule contextRule) {
if(contextRule.getMessageContext().getUser().equals(ContextRuleEvaluator.WILDCARD)
    || (contextRule.getMessageContext().getUser().equals(messageContext.getUser()))) {
  if(contextRule.getMessageContext().getApplication().equals(ContextRuleEvaluator.WILDCARD)
      || (contextRule.getMessageContext().getApplication().equals(messageContext.getApplication()))) {
    if(contextRule.getMessageContext().getService().equals(ContextRuleEvaluator.WILDCARD)
        || (contextRule.getMessageContext().getService().equals(messageContext.getService()))) {
      if(contextRule.getMessageContext().getOperation().equals(ContextRuleEvaluator.WILDCARD)
          || (contextRule.getMessageContext().getOperation().equals(messageContext.getOperation()))) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}

return false;
```

}

Context

```
public interface Context {    
  public String getUser();      
  public void setUser(String user);      
  public String getApplication();      
  public void setApplication(String application);      
  public String getService();      
  public void setService(String service);      
  public String getOperation();      
  public void setOperation(String operation);
}
```

ContextRule

```
public interface ContextRule {
  public Context getMessageContext();      
  public int getAllowedConcurrentRequests();      
}
```

Comment: You ask about comparing 2 lists, for which there are many good solutions, yet your code does not have a single list, but an object with a set of properties you are comparing against a constant or properties on another object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with a bit of refactoring and applying DRY, your approach would work as well as any other:

Move the matching logic inside the `Context` class:

```
@Override
public boolean match(Context anotherContext) {
    return match(this.getUser(), anotherContext.getUser()) &&
            match(this.getApplication(), anotherContext.getApplication()) &&
            match(this.getService(), anotherContext.getService()) &&
            match(this.getOperation(), anotherContext.getOperation());
}

private boolean match(String thisString, String thatString) {
    return thisString.equals(WILDCARD) || thisString.equals(thatString);
}
```

Then use it:

```
private boolean match(Context messageContext, ContextRule contextRule) {
    Context ruleContext = contextRule.getContext();
    return ruleContext.match(messageContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the list implementation overrides the equals method.

Is there a requirement not to use this?

```
list1.equals(list2);
```

javadoc:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface

This does the first two operations above, and calls each elements .equals(...) method to the others. So make sure you have properly overridden the equals method in your elements.

Comment: well Context and ContextRule are interfaces so i dont think equals is applicable here.

Comment: It most definitely is applicable here. Any thing that implements your interfaces also extends Object. Every object has a .equals() function. It is up to you to override it in your implementation if you don't want to use the Object.equals

Answer (score 0):

What you could do (but it would add unnecessary object creation):

```
private static boolean match(Context messageContext, ContextRule contextRule) {
  Context ruleContext = contextRule.getMessageContext();
  String[] interleaved = {
      ruleContext.getUser(), messageContext.getUser(), 
      ruleContext.getApplication(), messageContext.getApplication(),
      ruleContext.getService(), messageContext.getApplication(),
      ruleContext.getOperation(), messageContext.getOperation()};
  for (int i = 0; i < interleaved.length; i += 2) {
    if (!interleaved[i].equals(ContextRuleEvaluator.WILDCARD) && 
        !interleaved[i].equals(interleaved[i + 1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

It is possible to come up with many variants of this, but I think it would be hard to utilize list.equals() because you need to take the WILDCARD into account...

I would just rewrite the original check in a more concise form, utilizing a helper to reduce redundancy, e.g.

```
private static boolean matchValue(String ruleValue, String messageValue) {
  return ruleValue.equals(ContextRuleEvaluator.WILDCARD) 
      || ruleValue.equals(messageValue);
}

private static boolean match(Context messageContext, ContextRule contextRule) {
  Context ruleContext = contextRule.getMessageContext();
  return matchValue(ruleContext.getUser(), messageContext.getUser())
      && matchValue(ruleContext.getApplication(), messageContext.getApplication())
      && matchValue(ruleContext.getService(), messageContext.getService())
      && matchValue(ruleContext.getOperation(), messageContext.getOperation());
  }
}
```